I have some questions about using 出る and 出かける。
If I were to create a sentences about going to the store, and I made the sentence 「店に出かける。」,「コンビニに出かける。」, and 「スパーに出かける。」would those make sense in Japanese? Also, is it true that if I used 出る instead of 出かける, would it mean that the person would never come back or can I use them interchangeably depending on the meaning I was going for? If I added more stuff like 「スパーで買い物に出かける」does that make any sense and is is correct?

It should be スーパーに買い物に出かける.

Unless you are living in Northern Europe and go to a certain specific store.

「出る」 has the meaning of "moving (oneself) to the outside of" (somewhere/something). So if you are leaving from the home or building to the outside, you say 出る. It does not necessarily mean that you are going to permanently leave that place, but it can have such a meaning:

会社{かいしゃ}から出る - leave the company (this can also mean "physically leaving the building", which makes in temporary)
友達{ともだち}のチャットグループを出る - leave the chat group of a friend
大学{だいがく}を出る - leave (usually: graduate) the college

Please note that 出る can also mean other things:

ドラマに出る - feature in a dorama
オバケが出る - ghost(s) appear
お尻{しり}が出る - the buttcheeks show/poke out
血{ち}が出る - bleed

「出かける」, on the other hand, only has one meaning, and it is "to leave, for a limited period of time, for a general purpose". It sounds unnatural to use for a specific purpose:

友達{ともだち}と映画{えいが}に出かける - this does not sound natural
海{うみ}へ、釣{つ}りに出かける - this does not sound natural

Use 出る for the examples above instead.
The two can be used interchangeably in some cases, but there will be a difference in nuance: 山へでる and 山へ出かける both translate to "to go out to the mountains", but in the latter it is implied that there is an intention of returning soon.
Also, please note that "super" (for supermarkets) is spelled 「スーパー」 in katakana.
I referred to this blog entry for some detailed informations.

Oh my bad about the "super" part. I appreciate you breaking it down for me.

「釣りに出かける」は特に不自然ではないような気がするのですが、"general purpose" と "specific purpose" の違いって何ですか?

山へ出る sounds like the person regularly goes out in the mountain for some specific purpose, such as hunting or collecting mushrooms.

Jisho definitely fails to capture this nuance in its definitions.

@naruto 「ある特定の目的で向かう」と「散歩する、景色を見る、などの『何もしない』『ブラブラする』の概念に当てはまる行動を目的で向かう」の違いです。自分の日本語が大分訛ってるので、何が自然か不自然かこんがらがってしまう時があります。正直、ブログにある「映画に出かける」も、どこが不自然なのか不思議に思っましたが、まあそんなものなのかと。例文を変えた方が良いでしょうか？
